# Как правильно ставить ударение в слове "алкоголичка"?

Tags: фонетика

Как правильно: "алкогОличка" или "алкоголИчка". В пользу первого говорят ударения в словах "алкогОль" и "алкогОлик", в пользу второго - более частое употребление людьми.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В пользу правильного произношения говорит словарь: алкоголИчка - и никак иначе. 
Отсылки к однокоренным словам - плохой аргумент, когда дело касается переноса ударения на суффикс, тем более такой семантически нагруженный : мЕдик-медИчка, метОдика-методИчка,  элЕктрик-электрИчка.

Answer (score 0):

Правильно"алкоголИчка".